# Working with bootstrap modal and ember

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have a working version of bootstrap modals who open the nested list ('options') of a json who looks like that :

```
{ 
   product: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Some dope shoes',
      options: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Color' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Size' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Some dope',
      options: [
        { id: 3, name: 'Lenght' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Flavor' }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've wrote everything for modals with templates I did used any file component. The trick is to make uniq modal id. Url looks like :

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ma-modal{{optionid}}" title={{title}}>{{mmmh}}</a>
```

And modals looks like :

```
<div class="modal" id="ma-modal{{optionid}}"></div>
```

I don't feel confident about this code and because I'm learning ember I would like to know if doing all of this in template without any file components is something bad ?

Playing with the *ids* appears to me as a hack.

Comment: I don't use bootstrap but have implemented a modal using this excellent tutorial -- http://blog.atmartin.io/a-simple-modal-for-ember-v2-component-edition/ it uses Ember.js components

Comment: Yes read that too, really interesting one. Maybe gonna try to implement it that way. :/

Comment: There is also great addon: https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-modal-dialog

Comment: Are you agree that the way I'm doing it is not the best one ?

Comment: The liquid fire modal is probably the best and easiest to use that I've seen if you don't mind loading the entire liquid fire addon - http://ef4.github.io/liquid-fire/#/modals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinition, creating a component for modal is a way better solution, because:

- Ember will generate ids and you will have an access to rendered element inside lifecycle hooks, so in many cases there is no need to know an id.
- You will likely need to call some js-function to show a modal. Component gives a possibility to do this in the right moment (after rendering all elements) by using lifecycle hooks
- It is easy to re-use a component if needed.

You may found all necessary info about components in [documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/). Additionally, you can read about new (introduced in 1.13) lyfecycle hooks in [this](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_component-lifecycle-hooks) blog post.

And of course, you can use one of a many ember-cli addons, if you will find an appropriate one